# Convert NSSting to NSDecimalNumber based on locale

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nslocale, nsdecimalnumber

I want to convert a number which is input as `NSString` to `NSDecimalNumber` based on NSLocale.

for example

```
InputString => 110.50
Current Locale => en_FI
Expected output => 110.50
Actual output => 110

InputString => 110.50
Current Locale => en_US
Expected output => 110.50
Actual output => 110.50



InputString => 110,50
Current Locale => en_US
Expected output => 110.50
Actual output => 110


InputString => 110.50
Current Locale => en_US
Expected output => 110.50
Actual output => 110.50
```

I am using the following code to achieve this but its not working.

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.amountTextField.text locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

As mentioned above in 1st and 3rd i am not the desired output. Any idea what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Why are you using a localre if you are ignoring locale specifics?

Comment: Did you google the title of this question?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to specify `NumberFormatter`s `decimalSeparator` yourself and in input string replace `,` and `.` with same character you used in `decimalSeparator`.

```
import Foundation

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

func cleanNumberString(with string: String) -> String {
    let knownDecimalSeparators = [",", "."]
    let localSeparator = formatter.decimalSeparator ?? "."
    var cleanString = string;
    for separator in knownDecimalSeparators {
        cleanString = cleanString.replacingOccurrences(of: separator, with: localSeparator)
    }
    return cleanString
}

func number(with string: String) -> Double {
    let cleanString = cleanNumberString(with: string)
    let number = formatter.number(from: cleanString)
    return number?.doubleValue ?? 0
}

let string1 = "14,4"
let string2 = "14.4"

let cleanString1 = cleanNumberString(with: string1)
let cleanString2 = cleanNumberString(with: string2)

let number1 = number(with: string1)
let number2 = number(with: string2)
```

Same in Objective-C

```
@interface CleanNumberFormatter ()

@property (nonatomic) NSNumberFormatter *formatter;

@end

@implementation CleanNumberFormatter

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
        self.formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)cleanNumberStringWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSArray *knownDecimalSeparators = @[@",", @"."];
    NSString *localSeparator = self.formatter.decimalSeparator ?: @",";
    NSString *cleanString = [string copy];
    for (NSString *separator in knownDecimalSeparators) {
        cleanString = [cleanString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:separator withString:localSeparator];
    }
    return cleanString;
}

- (double)numberWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *cleanString = [self cleanNumberStringWithString:string];
    double number = [self.formatter numberFromString:cleanString].doubleValue;
    return number;
}

- (void)foo
{
    NSString *string1 = @"14.4";
    NSString *string2 = @"14,4";

    NSString *cleanString1 = [self cleanNumberStringWithString:string1];
    NSString *cleanString2 = [self cleanNumberStringWithString:string2];

    double number1 = [self numberWithString:string1];
    double number2 = [self numberWithString:string2];
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code decimal separator, i want to get it from device locale

Comment: @Madu decimal separator for `en_FI` is `,`, but in your input string it is `.`. So in your example everything works as expected.

Comment: yeah thats what i want if the device locale is en_FI and user enters 110.25. then it correctly changes gives me 110.25 instead of 110 only

Comment: @Madu my sample code gives you exactly what you want. Do you want to get string formatted correctly for current locale?

Comment: @Madu I've corrected answer. `cleanNumberString(with)` returns number string correct for current locale, `number(with)` returns double.

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the proper language.

Comment: @rmaddy I've added Objective-C version.

Answer (score 0):

The only numbers that do not have the expected output have a comma instead of a period and a period instead of a comma in the input. Try replacing that and see if it works as some locals use different decimal separators.

Comment: That's what want to achieve, that if user device locale is US and he enters number in some EU country format then it should change that number to the device locale format.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question right. You might want to look trough your string and replace the separators depending on the locale? Because the locale itself will ignore your decimals if the separator isn't the right one. Adding your own method to do that before converting to a number might be the best option.